# Check which button has been clicked using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I - using an if/else statement - check which button has been clicked?
Currently I'm using this **jQuery** code:

```
var nextBTN = $('.carousel .next');
var backBTN = $('.carousel .back');

if (nextBTN.trigger('click') == true) { /* is next button clicked? */
    console.log('nextBTN clicked');
} else if (backtBTN.trigger('click') == true) {
    console.log('backBTN clicked');
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="carousel">
    <ul>
        <li class="back"><span>Back</span></li>
        <li class="next"><span>Next</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to see the working example click on the link and you need to click on the dot of li in working example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').find("li").click(function(e) {
        var li = $(e.target);
        if (li.hasClass("next")) {
            alert("next")
        } else if (li.hasClass("back")) {
            alert("back")
        }


    });


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BtkCf/168/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".carousel .next, .carousel .back").on("click", function() {
  console.log($(this).hasClass("next") ? "Next clicked" : "Back clicked");
});
```

How about this one? You can even add a property like data-name, and you can do it much more cleaner:

```
$(".carousel .next, .carousel .back").on("click", function() {
  console.log($(this).data("name"));
});

<li class="back" data-name="back"><span>Back</span></li>
```

If you are sure that the li has only the back/next class, you can use `$(this).attr("class")`.

Comment: actually i have a function for slider.
function showSlider(){
  /* 90% of the code has been assigned here
  /* now i want if next request has been came from next button then move to next li image 

 $('ul').css('left',left+100) 
and if request has been came from back button then 
 $('ul').css('left',left-100) 
}